# What is this movie (probably about prison in space)?

Tags: story-identification, movie

Does anyone recognize the movie or the actor?

[image]

I only have a short snippet and from what I can make of the lines, it is about a prison, probably in space or on a spaceship. I guess it is some action or sci-fi movie, probably from the 80s or 90s.

The three guys in the second image (the prisoners) seem familiar too. The guy on the right looks like Ice-T, the one in the middle reminds me of Casper van Dien and the guy on the left looks familiar too. But I don't think they are these actors. Just to be safe, I have been through all the movies of both actors and I can't find anything that seems to fit.

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming you're the same person as https://community-imdb.sprinklr.com/conversations/i-need-to-know/who-is-this-actor-probably-from-the-90s-similar-to-dwayne-johnson/65f874dbed76fb277206d597

Comment: Yes, that is true.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is ***[Time Under Fire](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117912/)*** (1997).

> A US submarine runs into a time rift. A special unit goes on a mission to see what's on the other side. They find themselves in an alternate dystopian America, now a one-man dictatorship. They decide to help the rebels.

I recognised Jack Coleman, the actor in the foreground of your second image, and looked up his filmography to ID the film.

> [image: Image of the actor, Jack Coleman, from "Time Under Fire" (1997).]
>
> <sub>*Time Under Fire* (1997)</sub>

I couldn't find a trailer, but here's a 'killcount' video.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And the actor is Ben Jurand.